# How does a package like ATLAS know which fortran compiler to use?

Tags: compiling, gcc

How does a package like [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) know which compilers I have installed on my system?

For example, say that I install a local version of [gfortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gfortran), how do I "register it" in the system so that a package like [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) knows that I have it?

Comment: To "register" it, make sure that it is the first FORTRAN compiler found in the PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many unix applications, atlas has a `configure` script that you run as first part of the build process. Atlas' configure script will try to find a fortran compiler by trying known variants. You can also give it a specific path (`-Ss f77lib /path/goes/here`) or disable the use of fortran altogether (`--nof77`)

Answer (score 1):

Can't say about ATLAS specifically, but FORTRAN compilers have a few possible names, and it can just cycle through the possibilities. Taken to the limit, this is what the [GNU autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) do.